# Nhibernate simple self join

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, hql, criteria

I have a table with these fields:

```
ID (Primary key)
Name 
Some more data fields
```

I want to write a query that given a Name will give me all the rows with ID's bigger then the row with that name.

(Yes yes I know the name is not unique... in the system is.)

I want something like:

```
select *
From SomeTable as x
WHERE x.ID> (Select ID from SomeTable as y where y.Name LIKE :param)
```

or:

```
SELECT x
FROM SomeTable as x
JOIN SomeTable as y ON x.ID > Y.ID
WHERE Y.Name LIKE :Param
```

Of course I want the self join, and not the sub query.

---

BTW.
Criteria goes too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with a join in HQL.

But this HQL query is OK:

```
select f from Foo f where f.id > (select f2.id from Foo f2 where f2.name = :name)
```

If the subselect might return several IDs, you may also use

```
select f from Foo f where f.id > all (select f2.id from Foo f2 where f2.name = :name)
```

Comment: won't using a SubSelect in the HQL result in a SubSelect in the SQL? which will make it run a lot slower?

Comment: Why would a subselect necessarily result in a query that is a lot slower? Try to execute it, measure it against the query without the subselect, examine the explain plan and fine-tune the indices.